# jquery popup window from text link

Tags: popupwindow

I would like to create a link to a pop up window from a text link.
I have a heading titled Dedicated Desk which when moused over would open a op up window with t image of the desk.

is this possible?

Thanks,
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a tooltip plugin.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the link… I have looking at this site for the past week, but never made the connection with regards to the popup window